# stream & play incompleted mpeg-4 file

Tags: android, ffmpeg, mp4, mpeg-4

I'm using [MediaRecorder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setVideoEncoder%28int%29) to record screen on android device, the output file format is mpeg-4 and without a "moov atom" in front.

Now I want to stream this mpeg-4 file to remote server in real-time and make it playable, how can i achieve this?

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. An MP4 without a moov is worthless. A fragmented MP4 is possible, but you still need a moov at the start, and an moof for every fragment.